# Shopify limit product order quantity

Tags: shopify, shopifyscripts

I am new to Shopify and would like to know how I can set the max order quantity of a product to a specific number.

So product A max order qty 6

I am using the Symmetry theme.

I am comfortable editing code, just need to know where to find it. Also will a code change survive Shopify updates? Sorry I am switching over from Wordpress so getting familiar with this new system.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways you can achieve that:

1. Set max attribute on HTML input element or try to limit product using javascript. Note this is not recommended as customers can find an easy workaround for that limit using /cart/add/{:variantid} permalink.
2. Use an app to limit quantity from the Shopify app store.
3. The best approach would be to use Script Editor because customers cannot find a way to bypass that limitation. It works on both: the cart and checkout page. Even API calls to /cart.js will get computed quantity. I wrote a small snippet that works well:

```rb
class LimitProduct
  def initialize(variantId, quantity)
    @variant = variantId
    @max_qty = quantity
  end

  def run(cart)
    line_items = cart.line_items.select { |line_item| line_item.variant.id == @variant }
    return if line_items.empty?

    loop_items(cart, line_items)
  end

  def loop_items(cart, line_items)
    if @max_qty==0
      cart.line_items.delete_if {|item| item.variant.id == @variant }
    else
      line_items.each_with_index do |item,index|
        if item.quantity > @max_qty && @max_qty != 0
          reduceBy = item.quantity - @max_qty
          item.split(take: reduceBy)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

CAMPAIGNS = [
  LimitProduct.new(1234567890, 0), #first arg is variant id, second is max quantity
  LimitProduct.new(1111111111, 2)
]

CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
  campaign.run(Input.cart)
end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

Note that Script Editor is for Shopify Plus users

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way I can add your snipet code manually with Shopify Basic?

Comment: @Julien you need to have the script editor app installed, which according to the description in Shopify App Store is available only to Shopify Plus Merchants despite the fact that app itself is free. I think the script is not going to run if you are Shopify Basic

Comment: Thank you. My customer base is not the most tech savvy. How might I go about limiting the number of products ordered with method 1?

Comment: @Julien without knowing your code it will be hard to post any solution other than this one. You need to check how quantity controls are written in your store code